# What's the best practice for indexing unique text fields?

Tags: database, database-design, indexing, unique

I have a table with multiple text fields that cannot be part of the primary key for performance reasons. But the text fields need to have a full-text index AND be unique.

In such a case, is it appropriate to create a full-text index AND a unique index for each of these fields?

EDIT: I am using MySQL. I was hoping there was a general non-DB-specific answer, but apparently there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about SQL Server, then yes:  First you create a unique index on those text fields.  Then you create the full-text index on a subset of that unique index.

I don't really understand the question though because you literally cannot create a full-text index without already having a unique index.

NOTE:  If you are not talking about SQL Server then ignore this post and update the question to specify which DBMS you are using.